# Problem with stack algorithm to obtain the greatest number after remove n digits

Tags: c, stack

I am working on a stack algorithm that obtains the greatest number after removing `N` digits from any given number.

> Given `N` and a number with `k` digits, obtain the greatest number after removing `N` first digits from the given `k` digit number.

For example: `38271` and `N=2` => The greatest number is `871`

In my approach, I'm trying to read a sequence of numbers and digits to remove and get the greatest element of each one of them.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pilha.h"

int main()
{
   int m = 0, j;

   scanf("%d", &m); /* reads the number of sequences */
   getchar();

   for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      char *str = NULL;
      int ch;
      size_t size = 0, len = 0;

      /* Read char by char, allocating memory space when needed */
      while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
         if (len + 1 >= size)
         {
            size = size * 2 + 1;
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*size);
            if (str == NULL) {
               return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
         }
         str[len++] = ch;
      }

      str[len] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", str);

      char delim[] = " ";
      char *ptr = strtok(str, delim); /* split the string number from the number of removing digits */
      char *aux[2];

      int x = 0;
      while (ptr != NULL) {
         if (x > 1) {
            break;
         }
         aux[x] = ptr; /* stores into a variable to use later */
         ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
         x++;
      }

      int tam = strlen(aux[0]);
      printf("\nThe tam is : %d\n", tam);
      char number[tam];

      strcpy(number, aux[0]); /* copy to a new variable called number */
      printf("\nThe number string is : %s\n", number);

      int n = atoi(aux[1]); /* converting second parameter (number of removing digits) to integer */
      printf("\nThe splitted number is : %d\n", n);
      free(str);

      /* Converts the string number to integer */
      int arrayOfNumberDigits[tam];
      for (int l = 0 ; l < tam ; l++) {
         int data = number[l] - '0';
         arrayOfNumberDigits[l] = data;
      }

      int limit = tam - n; /* variable that holds the limit of digits of future greatest number */ 
      struct Stack* stack = createStack(limit);
      // push(stack, arrayOfNumberDigits[0]); /* push the first element to stack */

      int i = 0, stackSize = 0, helper = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
         while (!isEmpty(stack) && (arrayOfNumberDigits[i] > peek(stack)) && ((tam - i) >= limit)) {
            printf("%d popped from stack\n", pop(stack));
            helper++;
         }
         stackSize = stackSize - helper;
         if (stackSize < limit) {
            push(stack, arrayOfNumberDigits[i]);
            stackSize++;
         }
      }

      if (!isFull(stack)) {
         int x = 0;
         for(x = (tam - limit); x < tam; x++) {
            pop(stack);
         }
      }

      reverse(stack);
      while (!isEmpty(stack)) {
         printf("%d", pop(stack)); 
      }
      printf("\n");

      free(stack);

   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sadly, my current implementation does not work for cases like `192340623` with `N=2`. The problem is inside this piece of code, but I couldn't find what it is:

```c
int i = 0, stackSize = 0, helper = 0;
for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
   while (!isEmpty(stack) && (arrayOfNumberDigits[i] > peek(stack)) && ((tam - i) >= limit)) {
      printf("%d popped from stack\n", pop(stack));
      helper++;
   }
   stackSize = stackSize - helper;
   if (stackSize < limit) {
      push(stack, arrayOfNumberDigits[i]);
      stackSize++;
   }
}
```

Can somebody help find the issue in my current implementation, please?

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior*.  `int tam = strlen(aux[0]);` saves the length of `aux[0]` to `tam`, and does *not* include accounting for a string terminator. That's important because you then do: `char number[tam];` followed by a string copy which does `strcpy(number, aux[0]);`. Remember, `strcpy` sets a terminator, which you never provided space for. Therefore, this overruns your `number` array (which is in automatic storage, so you're likely smashing your stack). Therefore, UB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @WhozCraig! So I need to decrement by one my tam variable? Something like this int tam = strlen(aux[0])-1;?

Comment: Other way around. Leave `tam` the way it is, and increment the allocation of `number` to be `char number[tam+1];`. Not saying this will fix your problem, but UB is UB, and you don't want it in your code. That's a bug and needs to be addressed.

Comment: If aux[0]] is the the string containing the number, and aux[1] is the string representing the number of digits to remove from the start, then `strcpy( answer, &aux[0][aux[1]] )` will do it (assuming all of the char arrays have the proper lengths). Then convert `answer` to an int.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @WhozCraig! This bug doesn't fixed my problem, but it sure helped :)

Comment: This will work, @FredK! Thank you! But I would like to implement it by using a stack :(